# Subprocess command fails to return

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, subprocess

I have a thread which handles commands sent to a device. It opens a subprocess, sends the command to qmicli application (https://sigquit.wordpress.com/2012/08/20/an-introduction-to-libqmi/), gets a reply and the reply is dealt with.

This generally works fine for days/weeks of running. However I noticed that sometimes the thread would sometimes just stop doing anything when I make a `subprocess.Popen` call (the next lines of code do not run), the simplified code looks like this:

```
try:                
    self.qmi_process = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                       stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    # Log value of self.qmi_process happens here
    if self.qmi_process:
       out = self.qmi_process.communicate()
    else: 
        return "ERROR: no qmi_process"
    self.qmi_process = None 
    ret = ''.join(str(e) for e in out if e)
except:
    return "ERROR: Caught unhandled exception"
```

I have started logging the value of the `subprocess.Popen` call to see if the `communicate()` call was blocking or was it failing before this when the `subprocess` call is created. It turns out that for some reason the `subprocess.Popen` fails and `self.qmi_process` value is not logged, but my `Exception` code is not being called, any idea how that could happen?

`subprocess.Popen` does not return.

I have multiple threads calling popen, I've read this can cause deadlock in 2.7?